# Site keeps getting hacked and .htaccess changed

Tags: php, joomla

I have found that I have a similar attack to the one mentioned here

[giant regex hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328235/how-does-this-giant-regex-work)

The file keeps getting recreated and I cannot see from where its coming. How can I fix this? Anyone with a similar experience? I am running joomla 1.5.25

How can I trace the script that includes this file? How do I secure the site?

Comment: Check this utility could be useful: http://premprakashgupta.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Identify-Malicious-Pharama-Hacking-Attack-Scripts-in-your-Website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes, that's not a good situation. I've seen it happen a few times and more often than not the solution was to recreate the website from a clean Joomla install, copy over the data and reinstall components.

However first check that the permissions are ok (no 666, 777, etc) and definitely check the VEL to see if any of your extensions have know vulnerabilities http://docs.joomla.org/Vulnerable_Extensions_List

You could also check on the Inj3ctor database http://www.1337day.com/ . 
Most hacks like these happen via out of date extensions, open permissions, or as linuxeasy mentioned a poorly configured host.

Would highly recommend installing jhackguard or eyesite on the website. Eyesite will monitor your files and notify you when changes occur -http://extensions.lesarbresdesign.info/extensions/eyesite

Comment: Thanks for the eyesite name. I have been looking for this component. Lets try and see how it works. Used it once on another website. The files get recreated even after fresh install. I will update a new instance then deploy with the mentioned components and see. Its UGLY!!

Comment: Eyesite does not seem to restrict changes till I press acccept. I need something to 'disable' or lock file till I press accept on it. Do you have anything in mind?

Answer (score 3):

Its always recommended that you keep the permission of your .htaccess file as readable only.

```
chmod 0555 .htaccess
```

- But regarding the hack being created again and again, there could be just numerous reasons. Like the host not properly configured, such that, on a shared hosting, a script running for a different domain can access scripts for your own domain.
- Also check, what kind of files do you allow to upload, whether it's Admin or Frontend. Make sure, its not just *any* file upload is allowed. Executable files like PHP should not be allowed to be uploaded.

Comment: The hack was on another server and we moved to a new one. It is still being replicated on this one. .htaccess even on 0555 still gets changed. Its so weird how its running.

Comment: How do I restrict file uploads? Do I do this on .htaccess? Pretty much everything I put on .htaccess is overridden.

Comment: PHP file upload needs to be restricted by normal [File-Upload Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). Or if you have any modules/components/plugins in your joomla supporting file upload, check that it uploads limited types of files only. And File upload has nothing to do with .htaccess