# How to decode php shell?

Tags: php, malware

Yesterday i found a malware script on my site. I've removed it, but i want to know how it works. I can't decode the script, can anybody help me? I think it's php shell.
http://pastie.org/7901977

Comment: This backdoor looks like a backdoor detailed in detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3328247/2355701)

Comment: I try to use "echo gzinflate(base64_decode(''))" instead "eval gzinflate(base64_decode(''))" to view decode code, but i get error "Warning: gzinflate() [function.gzinflate]: data error"..

Comment: I used var_dump(). Here is the deobfuscated source  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5572978